# Generate Alpha numeric series in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can anyone please help me on this?

I want to generate a alpha numeric series like `A.1, A.2, A.3, A.4, B.1, B.2` which should increment automatically if I add new row.

I have a columns A and B which will be look like below.

```
A   B 
-----
1   A
1   A
1   A
1   A
2   B
2   B
3   C
3   C
3   C
```

The result must be look like below:

```
A   B   C
-----------
1   A   A.1
1   A   A.2
1   A   A.3
1   A   A.4
2   B   B.1
2   B   B.2
3   C   C.1
3   C   C.2
3   C   C.3
```

Comment: Use an `identity` column.  Don't construct an artificial key.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. but column A is identity column.can you give me the query with simple example

Comment: Identity with repeating values? Really?

Comment: @Perumal . . . Column A is not an identity column in this table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below query can return your expected result.

```
SELECT A, B, B + '.' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B ORDER BY A) AS VARCHAR) AS C
FROM TableName
```

Generating the Alpha numeric series is difficult. Using `ROW_NUMBER()` in computed column is also not possible. So for your case `view` is the right choice to achieve your expectation:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vw_MyAlphaNumbericOrder AS
SELECT A, B, B + '.' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B ORDER BY A) AS VARCHAR) AS C
FROM dbo.TableName
```

So when ever you are inserting a new record, then `SELECT * FROM dbo.vw_MyAlphaNumbericOrder` will return with the alpha numeric series as column `C`.

Sample execution with the given sample data:

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (A INT, B VARCHAR (2));

INSERT INTO @TestTable (A, B) VALUES
(1, 'A'),
(1, 'A'),
(1, 'A'),
(1, 'A'),
(2, 'B'),
(2, 'B'),
(3, 'C'),
(3, 'C'),
(3, 'C');

SELECT A, B, B + '.' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B ORDER BY A) AS VARCHAR) AS C
FROM @TestTable
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by below statement:

```
Select A,B,concat(B,'.',cast(row_number() over(partition by B order by B) as char(32))) as C
```

1.row_number() over (Partition by)-- will generate new row no. in each category of column B.
2.Cast -- will change the numeric value to character value where 32 specifies the length of data the field can hold
3. Concat-- will concatenate the required columns to create Alpha-numeric string

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.